# Azure Function Python Container - how to configure HTTP pings

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, azure-functions

I created a python based Azure Time triggered Function on custom container.
For many months it worked fine, but suddenly stopped working since last week.

Examining the logs shows this error

> 2021-07-20T08:39:57.871Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup
> request for container [Container Name]. Elapsed time = 199.7027324 sec
> 2021-07-20T08:40:13.018Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup
> request for container [Container Name]. Elapsed time = 214.8499071 sec
> 2021-07-20T08:40:28.119Z INFO  - Waiting for response to warmup
> request for container [Container Name]. Elapsed time = 229.9500529 sec
> 2021-07-20T08:40:29.161Z ERROR - Container [Container Name] for site
> [Site Name] did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time =
> 230.992183 sec 2021-07-20T08:40:29.162Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container [Container Name]_middleware for site [Site Name]
> 2021-07-20T08:40:29.496Z INFO  - Container [Container Name]_middleware
> for site [Site Name] initialized successfully and is ready to serve
> requests. 2021-07-20T08:40:29.508Z ERROR - Container [Container Name]
> didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See
> container logs for debugging.

I found many related posts but there is none that shows me how can i respond from my container to the HTTP ping? My container is hosting Azure function which is managed by Azure function runtime

Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169920/azure-web-app-for-container-failed-during-startup-didnt-respond-to-http-pin

Comment: It didn't work @Sajeetharan. I am not using https 443 port