# App service windows container start error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, windows-container

I've an asp.net core app that I want to run as windows container inside Azure app service.
The app uses PowerShell 5.1 and I'm not using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0, but building it as self contained. Snippets of the docker file are:

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 AS base
> ....
> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
> .. -c Release -o /app/publish --self-contained --runtime win-x64
> ...
> and then
> FROM base AS final
> ENTRYPOINT ["App.exe"]

The docker file is used to correctly build and push to ACR from azure devops pipeline, but when running the image in App Service it says:
*Unable to start container. Error message: Index was outside the bounds of the array*

I've also tried couple of other base images:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base
and
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS base
and they give same error.
I suspect it's because the image is not supported in app service.
Running locally on Windows 10 laptop is fine.
Does anyone know what windows images does app service support?

Comment: Please refer similar issue in [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/463587/windows-containers-unable-to-start-container-error.html)  once.

Comment: I've seen it and as I said trying with image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 gave the same error.

Answer (score 0):

When we are creating an App service its create an image itself which is auto generated
[image]

If you want to configure custom image please refer this ***Microsoft Documentation:***[***Configure a custom container for Azure App Service***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-windows)

As its failing while start the App service in windows container please check your console logs by Go to ***Advance Tools > Kudu console***

For more information please refer the below links

***MS Q&A:-*** [***Diagnose container start issues in Azure App Service for Linux***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/29678/diagnose-container-start-issues-in-azure-app-servi.html) & [***Azure App Service using a Windows container Failing and restarting***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/8381/azure-app-service-using-a-windows-container-failin.html)

- [***Troubleshooting Windows container in Azure app service***](https://serverfault.com/questions/1077479/troubleshooting-windows-container-in-azure-app-service)
- SO THREAD: [***Azure web app for container - failed during startup***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169920/azure-web-app-for-container-failed-during-startup-didnt-respond-to-http-pin)

Comment: I couldn't get it to run in Azure App Service. I tried with selecting Image Source: Azure Container Registry, then picking up my custom image, but then when running the App Service it again shows an error : 'Unable to start container. Error message: Index was outside the bounds of the array'. But I did managed to run it in Azure Container Instances, with exactly the same steps in the Docker configuration, so not sure why it doesn't run in App service